# Why does 2nd call to ShBrowseForFolder fail in this code?

Tags: delphi

The wrapper code below for calling ShBrowseForFolder works only once: if I call the Execute method a second time, the dialog does not appear on the "PtrIDL := ShBrowseForFolder(BrowseInfo);" call. Can anyone see what's wrong?

```
unit ShBrowseU;
(* Wrapper for ShBrowseForFolder
 *  22/01/2004
 *
 * Changes JD 6-7-2012:
 * - Inherit from TComponent
 * - Published properties
 * Changes JD 27-9-2012:
 * - Coinitialize call only once
 * Todo:
 * - Make UNCFolder, FolderCheck, Options and SelIconIndex published properties
 * - Catch Left/Top input < 0
 * - Component needs icon
 *)

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Dialogs, ShlObj ;

type
  TFolderCheck = function(Sender : TObject; Folder : string) : boolean of object;

  TShBrowseOption = (sboBrowseForComputer, sboBrowseForPrinter,
                     sboBrowseIncludeFiles, sboBrowseIncludeURLs,
                     sboDontGoBelowDomain, sboEditBox, sboNewDialogStyle,
                     sboNoNewFolderButton, sboReturnFSAncestors,
                     sboReturnOnlyFSDirs, sboShareable, sboStatusText,
                     sboUAHint, sboUseNewUI, sboValidate);
  TShBrowseOptions = set of TShBrowseOption;

  TShBrowse = class(TComponent)
  private
    FBrowseWinHnd : THandle;
    FCaption : string;
    FFolder : string;
    FFolderCheck : TFolderCheck;
    FInitFolder : string;
    FLeft : integer;
    FOptions : TShBrowseOptions;
    FSelIconIndex : integer;
    FTop : integer;
    FUserMessage : string;
    WinFlags : DWord;
    FCoInitialized: Boolean;
    procedure Callback(Handle : THandle; MsgId : integer; lParam : DWord);
    function GetUNCFolder : string;
    function IdFromPIdL(PtrIdL : PItemIdList; FreeMem : boolean) : string;
    procedure SetOptions(AValue : TShBrowseOptions);
  protected
    property BrowseWinHnd : THandle read FBrowseWinHnd write FBrowseWinHnd;
  published
    property Caption : string read FCaption write FCaption;
    property InitFolder : string read FInitFolder write FInitFolder;
    property Left : integer read FLeft write FLeft; // both Left & Top must be > 0 to position window
    property Top : integer read FTop write FTop;
    property UserMessage : string read FUserMessage write FUserMessage;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    function Execute : boolean;
    property Folder : string read FFolder;
    property UNCFolder : string read GetUNCFolder;
    property FolderCheck : TFolderCheck write FFolderCheck;
    property Options : TShBrowseOptions read FOptions write SetOptions;
    property SelIconIndex : integer read FSelIconIndex;
  end;

implementation

uses
  ActiveX;

const
  BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS    = $00000001;
  BIF_DONTGOBELOWDOMAIN   = $00000002;
  BIF_STATUSTEXT          = $00000004;
  BIF_RETURNFSANCESTORS   = $00000008;
  BIF_EDITBOX             = $00000010;
  BIF_VALIDATE            = $00000020;
  BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE      = $00000040;
  BIF_USENEWUI            = $00000040;
  BIF_BROWSEINCLUDEURLS   = $00000080;
  BIF_NONEWFOLDERBUTTON   = 0;
  BIF_UAHINT              = 0;
  BIF_BROWSEFORCOMPUTER   = $00001000;
  BIF_BROWSEFORPRINTER    = $00002000;
  BIF_BROWSEINCLUDEFILES  = $00004000;
  BIF_SHAREABLE           = $00008000;
  BFFM_VALIDATEFAILED     = 3;

  ShBrowseOptionArray : array[TShBrowseOption] of DWord =
                    (BIF_BROWSEFORCOMPUTER, BIF_BROWSEFORPRINTER,
                     BIF_BROWSEINCLUDEFILES, BIF_BROWSEINCLUDEURLS,
                     BIF_DONTGOBELOWDOMAIN, BIF_EDITBOX, BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE,
                     BIF_NONEWFOLDERBUTTON, BIF_RETURNFSANCESTORS,
                     BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS, BIF_SHAREABLE, BIF_STATUSTEXT,
                     BIF_UAHINT, BIF_USENEWUI, BIF_VALIDATE);

function ShBFFCallback(hWnd : THandle; uMsg : integer;
                       lParam, lpData : DWord) : integer; stdcall;
{connects the ShBFF callback general function to the
 Delphi method which handles it}
begin
  TShBrowse(lpData).Callback(hWnd, uMsg, lParam); // calls object's method
  Result := 0;
end;

constructor TShBrowse.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  Caption := 'Browse for folder';  // default
  UserMessage := 'Select folder';  // default
end;

procedure TShBrowse.Callback(Handle : THandle; MsgId : integer; lParam : DWord);
{Delphi method which handles the ShBFF callback}
var
  WorkArea, WindowSize : TRect;
  BFFWidth, BFFHeight : integer;
  SelOK : boolean;
begin
  FBrowseWinHnd := Handle;
  case MsgId of
    BFFM_INITIALIZED :
        begin
          if (FLeft = 0) or (FTop = 0) then begin
            {center the browse window on screen}
            GetWindowRect(FBrowseWinHnd, WindowSize);  // get ShBFF window size
            with WindowSize do begin
              BFFWidth := Right - Left;
              BFFHeight := Bottom - Top;
            end;
            SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETWORKAREA, 0, @WorkArea, 0); // get screen size
            with WorkArea do begin  // calculate ShBFF window position
              FLeft := (Right - Left - BFFWidth) div 2;
              FTop := (Bottom - Top - BFFHeight) div 2;
            end;
          end;
          {set browse window position}
          // SetWindowPos(FBrowseWinHnd, HWND_TOP, FLeft, FTop, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE);
          SetWindowPos(FBrowseWinHnd, HWND_TOPMOST, FLeft, FTop, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE);  // Always on top
          if (FCaption <> '') then
            {set Caption}
            SendMessage(FBrowseWinHnd, WM_SETTEXT, 0, integer(PChar(FCaption)));
          if (FInitFolder <> '') then
            {set initial folder}
            SendMessage(FBrowseWinHnd, BFFM_SETSELECTION, integer(LongBool(true)),
                        integer(PChar(FInitFolder)));
        end;
    BFFM_SELCHANGED :
        begin
          if Assigned(FFolderCheck) then
            {get folder and check for validity}
            if (lParam <> 0) then begin
              FFolder := IdFromPIdL(PItemIdList(lParam), false);
              {check folder ....}
              SelOK := FFolderCheck(Self, FFolder);
              {... en/disable OK button}
              SendMessage(Handle, BFFM_ENABLEOK, 0, integer(SelOK));
            end; {if (lParam <> nil)}
          {end; if Assigned(FFolderCheck)}
        end;
  {  BFFM_IUNKNOWN :;
    BFFM_VALIDATEFAILED :;  }
  end;
end;

procedure TShBrowse.SetOptions(AValue : TShBrowseOptions);
var
  I : TShBrowseOption;
begin
  if (AValue <> FOptions) then begin
    FOptions := AValue;
    WinFlags := 0;
    for I := Low(TShBrowseOption) to High(TShBrowseOption) do
      if I in AValue then
        WinFlags := WinFlags or ShBrowseOptionArray[I];
  end;
end;

function TShBrowse.Execute : boolean;
// Called to display the ShBFF window and return the selected folder
var
  BrowseInfo : TBrowseInfo;
  IconIndex  : integer;
  PtrIDL     : PItemIdList;     // Item identifier list
begin
  FillChar(BrowseInfo, SizeOf(TBrowseInfo), #0);
  IconIndex := 0;
  with BrowseInfo do begin
    hwndOwner := Self.FBrowseWinHnd;
    PIDLRoot  := nil;
    pszDisplayName := nil;
    lpszTitle := PChar(FUserMessage);
    ulFlags   := WinFlags;
    lpfn      := @ShBFFCallback;
    lParam    := integer(Self); // this object's reference
    iImage    := IconIndex;
  end;

//  if not FCoInitialized then FCoInitialized := Succeeded(CoInitializeEx(nil,COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED));

  PtrIDL := ShBrowseForFolder(BrowseInfo);
  if PtrIDL = nil then
    Result := false
  else begin
    FSelIconIndex := BrowseInfo.iImage;
    FFolder := IdFromPIdL(PtrIDL, true);   // This clears memory again
    Result := true;
  end; {if PtrIDL = nil else}
end;

function TShBrowse.IdFromPIdL(PtrIdL : PItemIdList; FreeMem : boolean) : string;
var
  AMalloc : IMalloc;
begin
  Result := '';
  SetLength(Result, MAX_PATH);
  SHGetPathFromIDList(PtrIDL, PChar(Result));
  Result := trim(Result);
  Result := string(PChar(Result));
  // When a PIDL is passed via BFFM_SELCHANGED and that selection is OK'ed
  // then the PIDL memory is the same as that returned by ShBrowseForFolder.
  // This leads to the assumption that ShBFF frees the memory for the PIDL
  // passed by BFFM_SELCHANGED if that selection is NOT OK'ed. Hence one
  // should free memory ONLY when ShBFF returns, NOT for BFF_SELCHANGED
  if FreeMem then begin
    {free PIDL memory ...}
    ShGetMalloc(AMalloc);
    AMalloc.Free(PtrIDL);
  end;
end;

function TShBrowse.GetUNCFolder : string;
  function GetErrorStr(Error : integer) : string;
  begin
    Result := 'Unknown Error : ' + IntToStr(Error); // default
    case Error of
      ERROR_BAD_DEVICE :         Result := 'Invalid path';
      ERROR_CONNECTION_UNAVAIL : Result := 'No connection';
      ERROR_EXTENDED_ERROR :     Result := 'Network error';
      ERROR_MORE_DATA :          Result := 'Buffer too small';
      ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED :      Result := 'UNC name not supported';
      ERROR_NO_NET_OR_BAD_PATH : Result := 'Unrecognised path';
      ERROR_NO_NETWORK :         Result := 'Network unavailable';
      ERROR_NOT_CONNECTED :      Result := 'Not connected';
    end;
  end;

var
  LenResult  : Cardinal;
  Error      : integer;
  PtrUNCInfo : PUniversalNameInfo;

begin
  {note that both the PChar _and_ the characters it
   points to are placed in UNCInfo by WNetGetUniversalName
   on return, hence the extra allocation for PtrUNCInfo}
  LenResult := 4 + MAX_PATH; // "4 +" for storage for lpUniversalName == @path
  SetLength(Result, LenResult);
  PtrUNCInfo := AllocMem(LenResult);
  // bh, 13-8-2012, PAnsiChar replaced by PWideChar
  Error := WNetGetUniversalName(PWideChar(FFolder), UNIVERSAL_NAME_INFO_LEVEL,
                                PtrUNCInfo, LenResult);
  if Error = NO_ERROR then begin
    Result := string(PtrUNCInfo^.lpUniversalName);
    SetLength(Result, Length(Result));
    end
  else
    Result := GetErrorStr(Error);
end;

end.
```

Note that I commented out the CoInitializeEx call, but that makes no difference.

This is XE2 code , a Win32 testapp under Win7 64 bits.

Thanks in advance
Jan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's plenty of strange looking code here, but I won't try to get in too deep. I would say though that FBrowseWinHnd is incorrectly typed. It is `HWND`. You don't have any `THandle`s in this unit. They should all be `HWND`.

The error is here:

```
with BrowseInfo do begin
  hwndOwner := Self.FBrowseWinHnd;//oops, this is wrong
```

That set's the dialog's owner window to be the window handle that represented the dialog the last time it was shown. And that's why it fails only at the second time of asking.

Clearly that's wrong. Simply remove this line of code and leave `hwndOwner` as 0.  If you want to give the dialog an owner, change the signature of `Execute` to receive the owner window handle, and then pass it on to the dialog.

---

How would one go about debugging an API call that succeeds once, and then fails when called again? The first step is to look at the value the parameters and see if they vary from one call to the next. And indeed doing exactly that is how I identified the problem.

Comment: Thanks David, I'll look into it. I just noticed that the code fails with the component on my form at design time, but it works with runtime creation "procedure TFrmBrowse.BtnBrowseClick(Sender: TObject);
var XMLFolderBrowser: TShBrowse;
begin
   XMLFolderBrowser:= TShBrowse.Create(Self); 
   ShowMessage(BoolToStr(XMLFolderBrowser.Execute,true));
end;"  That would fit with it being a window/handle/owner issue.

Comment: @Jan - Your run-time test executes the code once per component creation, execute it twice and it'll probably fail.